# why does ListIterator.add does not throw ConcurrentModificationException but list.add below throw exception?

Tags: java, data-structures

Hi I am trying to understand how add operation on ListIterator works. I don't understand why line #7 lets me add item to iterator and line #8 throws ConcurrentModificationException. What is the difference adding item to ListIterator vs add item to List. Both are trying to achieve the same thing.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("hi");
list.add("whats up");
list.add("how are you");
list.add("bye");

ListIterator<String> i = list.listIterator();

while (i.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(i.next());
    list.add("Sample"); // Line #7
    i.add("Test"); // Line #8
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Is the title correct? `List.add` does not throw CME, `ListIterator.add` does. The title says otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

`List.add` appends the specified element to the end of this list.

`ListIterator.add` inserts the specified element roughly speaking "after the current position". More precisely, the element is inserted immediately before the element that would be returned by `next()`, if any, and after the element that would be returned by `previous()`, if any. Also adding an element with `ListIterator.add` does not produce `ConcurrentModificationException`.

You get `ConcurrentModificationException` because you call `list.add` while iterating over the list iterator. This is due to the [fail-fast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#fail-fast) feature:

> The iterators returned by this class's `iterator` and `listIterator` methods are *fail-fast*: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own `remove` or `add` methods, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

This is exactly what is happening. You modify the list directly (not through iterators own methods).